# Issue in Boot , platform device creation failed: -16

Tags: release-loki, boot, startup

cpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16 Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) Hardware name : HP HP pavilion notebook/820C , BIOS F.07 05/27/2016

I have dual boot Windows 10 + Elementary Os(Ubuntu 16.04+)

Everything is working fine for last two years, today when I opened elementary os and run sudo apt upgrade.

In meanwhile I'm working with Firefox and vs code , suddenly my pc was slow down. Yeah that's genuine because upgrades are progressing... Firefox frized due to progress in upgrades. So i decided to shut down my laptop. When i startup my laptop the above msgs are flash in screen.

How can i boot my elementary without settings and data loss.

Thanks

Comment: Well its difficult to restore from that. You can recover your data with a live USB and then you'd need to install elementary again. By the way, you can install Juno, the next version of elementary already!

Comment: I had solved the issue without format the device. On startup elementary has an advanced option their I switch the old kernel.

Comment: Okay. Make sure you update the kernel but this time don't stop it!